# Typescript import/export issue

Tags: typescript

Trying to import class is failing. I'm using Sublime Text 3.

Exporting class dog and importing into class House.

filename Dog.ts

```
export class Dog {
    static public sound = "Woof"; 
}
```

filename House.ts

```
import { Dog } from "./Dog"

class House {
    TestDogSound () {
        alert(Dog.sound);
    }
}
```

All house see the dog object but it is not working 
getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "Dog" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

Hope it's clear enough, advice needed,
Thanks.

Edit : adding tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonJs",
        // "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true

    },
    "files": [
        "Dog.ts",
        "House.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is this a runtime error?

Comment: Yes  , the build goes fine.

Comment: Well, then you're not loading `Dog.js`, or you try to use it before it has been loaded. How are you loading modules?

Comment: I thought i was by export / import , and loading the requireJs in my html.

Comment: To my understanding the export translate it to requireJs asynchrone method and after it returns i should have the Dog class.

Comment: Please share your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @NitzanTomer Tnanks , dont have it , i'll try figure what it means.

Comment: You are probably compiling for the wrong module system. You need to specify to which system to compile. Check out the `--module` arg in the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: Compiled to requireJs give a result of :                                                                 require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports, Dog_1)

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Your problem will be that there is other code in the two modules that creates a circular dependency between them, possibly via other modules.